# Trace-preserving $\Rightarrow$ Norm-preserving?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\theta\in\text{Aut}(\frak{M},\tau)$, where $\frak{M}$ a von-Neumann algebra and $\tau$ a faith, finite, normal trace. Does $\theta$ preserve the norm structure? (Here assumed, that $\frak{M}$ acts on some fixed $\mathcal{H}$.)

If there is a way to express $\|a\|$ in terms of trace, that would be useful.

For example it holds at least that $\|a\|_{p}=\text{Sup}\{|\tau(ab)|:\|b\|_{q}=1\}$
for $p,q\in[1;\infty]$ with $1/p+1/q=1$ and $p<\infty$. Were this or something similar to in the case of $p=\infty$ hold, then one could find a positive answer.

(Note: here $\|a\|_{p}=\sqrt[p]{\tau(|a|^{p})}$ for $p<\infty$ and $\|a\|_{\infty}=\|a\|$.)

Comment: Sorry! The answer is obvious and has nothing to do with trace. So long as $\theta$ is an automorphism of the vN-algebra, it for positive elements, $a\in\frak{M}$, that $\theta(a)$ and $a$ have the same spectrum and thus the same norm. Thus it holds for general elements, $a\in\frak{M}$, that $\|\theta(a)\|^{2}=\|\theta(a)^{\ast}\theta(a)\|=\|\theta(a^{\ast}a)\|=\|a^{\ast}a\|=\|a\|^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

User60403 answered the question in a comment.  Yes, because $*$-automorphisms of von Neumann algebras are always isometric.

More generally, if $\theta:A\to B$ is a $*$-homomorphism between C*-algebras $A$ and $B$, then $\|\theta(a)\|\leq \|a\|$ for all $a\in A$, and $\theta$ is isometric if it is injective.